# Cutting cheese into chunks

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, geometry

Into how many chunks can one cut a round piece of cheese with n straight cuts?

Consider the $3D$ version

My try:

f(x) = number of pieces and $'x'$ as number of cuts.

$f(1)=2$

$f(2)= 2 + f(1)$

and therefore

$f(n) = n + f(n-1) $ and after solving the recurrence relation I got

$f(n) = [n^{2}+n+2]/2 $

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand what "straight" means in 3D. Do you means planar?

Comment: Just Imagine this:
If you are given a knife , how would cut a pizza or cheese?

Comment: Well, $f(3) = 8$, so this is not correct. Consider slice a $2\times2\times2$ cube into 8 pieces by 3 slices...

Comment: No, there will be 7 pieces not 8 :/

Comment: Why 7 pieces? Consider a cube $([-1..1],[-1..1],[-1..1])$. Slice it by 3 planes $xy, xz, yz$. You have 8 pieces correspond to 8 octants. You are considering 3D, don't you?

Comment: I got it, I did it for 2D version. You are correct

Comment: How can I approach this for 3D?

Comment: Do the cuts have to pass through the center? If so, I count 6 pieces with three cuts... If not, 4, 5, 6 or 7 pieces are possible. Even 8 if you consider cuts in 3D, as @user202729 mentioned.

Comment: There is nothing else mentioned in the question so we can assume that there is no condition